# Horizontal alignment of table rows with CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am stuck with my companies CRM for creating surveys. I can customize the JavaScript and CSS of the survey but not the junk HTML code it puts out.

I am trying to get answers for a survey question laid out as a range.

Example:

[image: Example of a range of answers]

But I can't seem to target the answers in order to either apply a display: inline attribute or a float: left attribute.

See the HTML code which I cannot edit below.

```
<div class="QuestionContainer"
    id="cont_id_f_6b97f5812768e81180f1005056a85b23" questionIndex="12">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px; color:#000000;">
            <td class="alignTop"><input
                    id="multioption0_6b97f5812768e81180f1005056a85b23"
                    name="multioption0_6b97f5812768e81180f1005056a85b23"
                    type="radio"
                    value="1 - Not at all satisfied"
                    onclick="ShowOneRadio(this);" />
            </td>
            <td class="alignTop">1 - Not at all satisfied</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:13px; color:#000000;">
            <td class="alignTop"><input
                    id="multioption1_6b97f5812768e81180f1005056a85b23"
                    name="multioption1_6b97f5812768e81180f1005056a85b23"
                    type="radio"
                    value="2 - Somewhat satisfied" onclick="ShowOneRadio(this);"
                    />
            </td>
            <td class="alignTop">2 - Somewhat satisfied</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom` for `td`s might solve the problem?

Comment: please show what you've tried there shouldn't be an issue styling this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex box is awesome i'd suggest looking at its api

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

If you have access to change the HTML i would as the markup you've used is very verbose for what you're trying to achieve.

please let me know if you have any questions

```css
.QuestionContainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.QuestionContainer tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

tr {
  padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="QuestionContainer" id="cont_id_f_6b97f5812768e81180f1005056a85b23" questionIndex="12">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="alignTop">
      <input  type="radio" value="1 - Not at all satisfied" onclick="ShowOneRadio(this);" />
      </td>
      <td class="alignTop">1 - Not at all satisfied</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alignTop"><input type="radio" value="2 - Somewhat satisfied" onclick="ShowOneRadio(this);" />
      </td>
      <td class="alignTop">2 - Somewhat satisfied</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alignTop">
      <input type="radio" value="1 - Not at all satisfied" onclick="ShowOneRadio(this);" />
      </td>
      <td class="alignTop">3 - Not at all satisfied</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alignTop">
      <input type="radio" value="2 - Somewhat satisfied" onclick="ShowOneRadio(this);" />
      </td>
      <td class="alignTop">4 - Somewhat satisfied</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem. I am using surveying software with a WYSIWYG program that has read-only HTML. Thank goodness for the ability to edit the CSS at least.

Flex Box worked great. I appreciate the help!

Comment: glad it helped have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

```
.QuestionContainer tr {
    float:left;
}
```

Probably you would also want to add a margin to it, like margin: 10px or so.